# Magento communicating with another system

Tags: web-services, magento

I'm building a magento (1.9CE) store which needs to interface with another system and I could use some guidance.

Although not particularly relevant, I'm communicating with the 'other' system using web services (it's on another server) but ***what I need help with is finding the places where I need to put in code to do what I want***.

There are three major functions that I need to implement:-

1. When a user clicks on the product detail page I need to make a call to check the stock levels on the other system, update the magento stock levels and THEN display the product detail page.
2. When a sale is completed, I need to send details of that sale to the other system.
3. When a new product is added I need to communicate with the other system.  This may be a bit more complex because there are a few checks I need to do during the 'add product' process, for example, check the SKU is valid, that tghe product doesn't already exists, etc.  I think until I start coding this I shan't realise the full extent of this functionality!

Any guidance gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this might (and probably will) dramatically slow down your store, if you want real-time information, I guess the easiest way would be with observers.

1. You can use `catalog_controller_product_init_before`: This will trigger when the product detail page is starting loading, so you should be able to upload the stock at this point, before the page has finished loading, so that if there is no stock it will not be buyable, which I guess that's what you want.
2. You can use `sales_order_place_after`: This will be triggered after a new order has been placed and saved in the database.
3. You can use `catalog_product_new_action` or `catalog_product_save_after`: Depending on how you create your products the first one might not be triggered. The second one will always be triggered once a product (new or existing) has been saved, so at this point you will need to check if the product is new or existing, and do your stuff depending on that.

For an example of how to create an extension and usage of observer events, check [this out](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105).
I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for that reply.  It's pointing me in the right direction.  I was heading towards event observers but there seemed to be so many to choose from.  I'm also hopeful that I can do a lot of the tasks with a cron job and so avoid some of these 'slow-downs' - particularly the stock enquiry.

Comment: That approach makes sense.